# On() doesn't work after html change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/P9rs6/

HTML

```
<span class="js-make-input" data-id="1" data-value="5">5</span>
```

jQuery

```
    $('.js-make-input').on('dblclick', function(){
    var itemID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value');

    $(this).attr('class', 'js-edit-row');

    $(this).html(' <input type="text" value="' + value + '" data-id="' + itemID + '" style="width: 45px" /> ');
});

$('.js-edit-row').on('dblclick', function(){
    $(this).attr('class', 'js-make-input');
    $(this).html(value);
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value', value);

});
```

I can understand, why it doesn't work after second dblclick.

Comment: You might also want to take a look [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ks_27q) for how to create DOM objects without string concatenation.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @jeroenvisser101 thank you! I'll try to use your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events on dynamically added elements. Like this:

```
$(document).on('dblclick','.js-make-input', function(){ /*Your code here*/ });
```

This is just for simple example, it is better to bind it on element closer to your button that is already on page when it first loads rather than on `document`.

Comment: Ideally, substitute `document` for a common parent instead. i. e. the form.

Comment: This answer could be improved by describing *why* OP's code didn't work.